bar chart axis issue
I have made a bar char which have two columns per category. These columns can have positive or negative values. The y-axis values does not seem to be consistent even after setting the number of y-axis values tick. I am  quite curious on how that property is being computed

tickCount uses some internal logic and heuristics so unfortunately it can't always guarantee you will see the number of ticks you specify. You can control it with the values attribute though if you want full control. In your case, you're overriding through the use of domainMin (-317) and domainMax (317). For instance:

produced by the following. You need to ensure you calculation for your domain min and max are appropriate.
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 817,
  "height": 278,
  "autosize": {"type": "fit", "contains": "padding"},
  "padding": {"bottom": 2, "right": 9, "left": 5},
  "config": {
    "axis": {
      "labelFont": "HelveticaNeueLTW01-55Roman",
      "titleFont": "HelveticaNeueLTW01-55Roman"
    }
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "capital_flows",
      "values": [
        {"label": "Aug 2023", "capital_inflow": 0, "capital_outflow": 0},
        {"label": "Sep 2023", "capital_inflow": 0, "capital_outflow": 0},
        {"label": "Oct 2023", "capital_inflow": 0, "capital_outflow": 0},
        {"label": "Nov 2023", "capital_inflow": 0, "capital_outflow": 0},
        {"label": "Dec 2023", "capital_inflow": 0, "capital_outflow": -317.18},
        {"label": "Jan 2024", "capital_inflow": 0, "capital_outflow": -117.19},
        {"label": "Feb 2024", "capital_inflow": 0, "capital_outflow": 0},
        {"label": "Mar 2024", "capital_inflow": 0, "capital_outflow": 0},
        {"label": "Apr 2024", "capital_inflow": 0, "capital_outflow": 0},
        {"label": "May 2024", "capital_inflow": 0, "capital_outflow": 0},
        {"label": "Jun 2024", "capital_inflow": 0, "capital_outflow": 0},
        {"label": "Jul 2024", "capital_inflow": 0, "capital_outflow": 0},
        {"label": "Aug 2024", "capital_inflow": 0, "capital_outflow": 0}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "split(datum.label, ' ')", "as": "label"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "parsed",
      "source": ["capital_flows"],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "fields": [
            "capital_inflow",
            "capital_inflow",
            "capital_outflow",
            "capital_outflow"
          ],
          "ops": ["min", "max", "min", "max"],
          "as": ["min_value1", "max_value1", "min_value2", "max_value2"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.max_value1 == 0 && datum.max_value2 == 0 ? 1 : datum.max_value1 > datum.max_value2 ? abs(datum.max_value1) : abs(datum.max_value2)",
          "as": "mergedMax"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.min_value1 == 0 && datum.min_value2 == 0 ? -1 : datum.min_value1 < datum.min_value2 ? abs(datum.min_value1) : abs(datum.min_value2)",
          "as": "mergedMin"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.mergedMax > datum.mergedMin ? datum.mergedMax : datum.mergedMin",
          "as": "max"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "-(datum.max)", "as": "min"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "band",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "capital_flows", "field": "label"}
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "zero": false,
      "domain": {"data": "parsed", "field": "limit"},
      "domainMin": {"signal": "-400"},
      "domainMax": {"signal": "400"}
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "scale": "x",
      "zindex": 1,
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "labelColor": "#85868C",
      "labelAlign": "center",
      "labelLineHeight": 16.8,
      "labelFontWeight": "normal",
      "labelPadding": 8,
      "labelOpacity": 1,
      "domain": false,
      "domainColor": "#e5e5e5",
      "domainWidth": 1,
      "ticks": false
    },
    {
      "orient": "left",
      "scale": "y",
      "zindex": 0,
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "labelColor": "#85868C",
      "labelLineHeight": 16.8,
      "labelFontWeight": "normal",
      "labelPadding": 8,
      "labelOpacity": 1,
      "domain": false,
      "domainColor": "#e5e5e5",
      "grid": true,
      "gridOpacity": 0.5,
      "ticks": false,
      "tickCount": 4,
      "gridDash": {"signal": "datum.value == 0 ? [0,0] : [4,4]"},
      "encode": {
        "labels": {
          "update": {
            "text": {
              "signal": "if(abs(datum.value) >= 1e9, format(datum.value/1e9, '$,.1~f') + 'B', if(abs(datum.value) >= 1e6, format(datum.value/1e6, '$,.1~f') + 'M', if(abs(datum.value) >= 1e3, format(datum.value/1e3, '$,.1~f') + 'K', format(datum.value, '$,.2~f'))))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "inflow",
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "capital_flows"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "xc": {"scale": "x", "field": "label", "band": 0.5},
          "width": {"value": 14},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "capital_inflow"},
          "y2": {
            "scale": "y",
            "value": 0,
            "offset": {"signal": "datum.capital_inflow < 0 ? 1.5: 0"}
          },
          "fill": {"value": "#68c487"},
          "cornerRadiusTopLeft": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_inflow > 0 ? '1' : '0'"
          },
          "cornerRadiusTopRight": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_inflow > 0 ? '1' : '0'"
          },
          "cornerRadiusBottomLeft": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_inflow > 0 ? '0' : '1'"
          },
          "cornerRadiusBottomRight": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_inflow > 0 ? '0' : '1'"
          },
          "stroke": {"signal": "datum.capital_inflow !== 0 ? '#68c487': null"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 1.5},
          "fillOpacity": {"signal": "datum.capital_inflow !== 0 ? 1 : 0"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "outflow",
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "capital_flows"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "xc": {"scale": "x", "field": "label", "band": 0.5, "offset": 17},
          "width": {"value": 14},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "capital_outflow"},
          "y2": {
            "scale": "y",
            "value": 0,
            "offset": {"signal": "datum.capital_outflow < 0 ? 1.5: 0"}
          },
          "fill": {"value": "#FFB066"},
          "cornerRadiusTopLeft": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_outflow > 0 ? '1' : '0'"
          },
          "cornerRadiusTopRight": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_outflow > 0 ? '1' : '0'"
          },
          "cornerRadiusBottomLeft": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_outflow > 0 ? '0' : '1'"
          },
          "cornerRadiusBottomRight": {
            "signal": "datum.capital_outflow > 0 ? '0' : '1'"
          },
          "stroke": {"signal": "datum.capital_outflow !== 0 ? '#FFB066': null"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 1.5},
          "fillOpacity": {"signal": "datum.capital_outflow !== 0 ? 1 : 0"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


thanks @davidebacci, I agree with the limitations on tickCount as it is being computed within Vega. Unfortunately, I can’t really set something like that in my domainMin and domainMax as the data being passed is dynamic and varies. So sometimes, the tickCount does display as I expected and sometimes not..

I tried multiplying the domainMin and domainMax by 1.5 / 2 and other values but I guess it is a hit or miss depending on my data without knowing how it is being computed

You need some hard logic in order to come up with a solution. What are the rules you want to have to create your domain min and max? There are lots of approaches you could take with rounding so it really comes down to how you expect it to behave.

Based on observation the ideal min and max would be something like this: max data value is 1071 -> domainMax is 1500, max data value is 317.18 -> domainMax is 400, max value is 1.9M -> domainMax is 2M. Is this logic possible?

Those seem like magic numbers and a bit arbitrary. The code I posted in the new answer works for the last two. The first one for 1071 to 1500 could be incorporated in a similar manner with a few more ternary statements but it seems easier to round to 2k rather than 1.5k.

Make sense, I have settled that data set into rounding the domainMax value to $2k now.

What about something like this:
 "signals": [
    {"name": "a", "update": "pluck(data('parsed'), 'max')"},
    {"name": "b", "update": "length(split(toString(a),'.')[0])"},
    {
      "name": "c",
      "update": "ceil(a/toNumber(pad('1',b,'0')))*toNumber(pad('1',b,'0'))"
    }
  ],


 "domainMax": {"signal": "c"}



thanks @davidebacci, this seems to work on most cases. Are you able to check on why it does not work for the second sample data set I have added above? The tickCount is still not 4 and only up to $5k. I am expecting it to be -$10k and $10k respectively.

This seems to work. I think you need a bit more logic in the code to get it to work in all cases though.   {"name": "b", "update": "length(split(toString(a),'.')[0])+1"},
